# What is the JSDoc syntax to consistently define a callback with a generic?

Tags: typescript, svelte, jsdoc, tsd-jsdoc

I have the following JSDoc definition of an identity function:

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @callback id
 * @param {T} x
 * @returns {T}
 */
```

When I use it with a plain function definition, it works as expected, no complaints:

```
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store'

/**
 * @template T
 * @type {id<T>}
 */
function identity (x) {
  return x
}
const number = identity(writable(42))
identity(derived(number, $number => $number * 2))
```

It correctly infers that `number` is a `Writable<number>` (from the Svelte definitions), and therefore `$number` is a `number`.

However when defining that function inside another one, the types returned from `identity` are lost:

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {(identity: id<T>) => unknown} definition
 */
function Model (definition) {
  /**
   * @template T
   * @type {id<T>}
   */
  function identity (x) {
    return x
  }
  return definition(identity)
}

Model(function (identity) {
  const number = identity(writable(42))
  identity(derived(number, $number => $number * 2))
})
```

In this case `number` is `any`, and therefore `$number` is `unknown`, and so it complains: "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type."

Why is there a difference between the two? and how can it be tweaked to ensure that it infers the correct types?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter that this doesn't work (yet) in Svelte?
"Stores must be declared at the top level of the component (this may change in a future version of Svelte)" https://svelte.dev/repl/a8febc33018f4aab845b201769b5a709?version=3.46.4

Comment: @BobFanger Thanks. This question is more about how to annotate the code to prevent VSCode warnings rather than the code itself.